# Laravel 7, SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed when trying to add a relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm running Laravel 7 on PHP 7.4 with MySQL 8.0.

I have three tables, `User`, `Company` and `Department`, with their respective models and factories.

I created a test where I'm adding the relationship:

```php
// MyTest.php
$user = factory(User::class)->create();

$company = factory(Company::class)->make();
$company->user()->associate($user);
$company->create(); // it fails here because of NOT NULL constraint, companies.user_id

$department = factory(Department::class)->make();
$department->company()->associate($company);
$department->create();
```

I get the following error: `Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: companies.user_id (SQL: insert into "companies" ("updated_at", "created_at") values (2020-03-10 07:27:51, 2020-03-10 07:27:51))`

My table schema is defined like this:

```php
// users
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->string('phone');
    $table->integer('user_type');
    $table->string('password');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});

// companies
Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('contact_email');
    $table->string('contact_phone');
    $table->timestamps();
});

// departments
Schema::create('departments', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('company_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('contact_email');
    $table->string('contact_phone');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

It is my understanding that there should be no NULL-values in SQL-tables, which is why I am deliberately trying to avoid `->nullable()` in my migrations. Especially for foreign keys like these.

EDIT:

I tried doing it this way, I also made a pivot table for `users_companies`. Now I can attach a company, but I'm still getting an SQL-error when doing the test this way:

```php
$user = factory(User::class)->create();
$company = factory(Company::class)->create();

$user->companies()->attach($company);
$company->departments()->create([
    'name' => 'Department 1',
    'contact_email' => 'department1@example.test',
    'contact_phone' => '123456789',
]);
```

This also fails with the error stated below:

```php
$company = factory(Company::class)->create();
$company->departments()->save(factory(Department::class)->make());
```

The error is this: `Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: departments.company_id (SQL: insert into "departments" ("name", "contact_email", "contact_phone", "company_id", "updated_at", "created_at") values (Department 1, department1@example.test, '123456789', ?, 2020-03-11 07:59:31, 2020-03-11 07:59:31))`.

`CompanyFactory.php`

```php
<?php

/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory */

use App\Company;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(Company::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => 'Company 1',
        'contact_email' => 'company@example.test',
        'contact_phone' => '123456789',
    ];
});
```

**Factories**

`DepartmentFactory.php`

```php
<?php

/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory */

use App\Department;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(Department::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => 'Department 1',
        'contact_email' => 'department1@example.test',
        'contact_phone' => '123456789',
    ];
});
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're not doing it like `$user->companies()->save($company)`?

Comment: In your `Company` model, is the `user_id` field [specified as `$fillable`?](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#mass-assignment)

Comment: Please see my update. I also tried setting `company_id` as fillable in the `Department`-model.

Comment: You're asking about problems with your relationships, but you aren't showing the relationships...

Comment: Whoops... You're right. Seems the problem was with $this->hasMany in the Company model: `return $this->hasMany(Department::class, 'company_id', 'department_id');`, just removed the explicit IDs, probably had them the wrong way around. The migrations work, and they're compliant with the Laravel 7 documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some problems with your table structure are very clear at first glance.

- It appears you're trying to add a `user_id` column to your `companies` table. This is not a good idea, assuming your companies have more than one employee.
- If you want to use `NOT NULL` columns, you'd better define a [default value](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#column-modifiers) for each of them.

So we can start by writing the migrations something like this, including pivot tables for the company/user and department/user relationships:

```php
// companies
Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('contact_email')->default('');
    $table->string('contact_phone')->default('');
    $table->timestamps();
});

// departments
Schema::create('departments', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignIdFor(Company::class)->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('contact_email')->default('');
    $table->string('contact_phone')->default('');
    $table->timestamps();
});

// users
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->string('name')->default('');
    $table->string('phone')->default('');
    $table->integer('user_type')->default(0);
    $table->string('password');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('company_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignIdFor(Company::class)->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
    $table->foreignIdFor(User::class)->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
});

Schema::create('department_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignIdFor(Department::class)->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
    $table->foreignIdFor(User::class)->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
});
```

Now we have links between tables. A department is part of a company; a user can be part of multiple departments and/or multiple companies. This leads to the following [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships):

```php
class User extends Model {
    // many-to-many
    public function companies() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(App\Company::class);
    }
    // many-to-many
    public function departments() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(App\Department::class);
    }
}

class Company extends Model {
    public function departments() {
        // one-to-many
        return $this->hasMany(App\Department::class);
    }
    public function users() {
        // many-to-many
        return $this->belongsToMany(App\User::class);
    }
}

class Department extends Model {
    public function company() {
        // one-to-many (inverse)
        return $this->belongsTo(App\Company::class);
    }
    public function users() {
        // many-to-many
        return $this->belongsToMany(App\User::class);
    }
}
```

Now code like this should work:

```php
$user = factory(User::class)->create();
$company = factory(Company::class)->create();

$user->companies()->attach($company);
$company->departments()->create([
    'name' => 'Department 1',
    'contact_email' => 'department1@example.test',
    'contact_phone' => '123456789',
]);
$user->departments()->attach($company->departments->first());
```

Specifically, the `attach` method is used for updating many-to-many relationships, which you did not appear to have defined, based on your original table layout.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer, actually pointed me towards an issue with naming scheme of a completely unrelated table (pluralization of the word Child is not Children in Laravel ), which makes `$table->foreignId('child_id')` break. I disagree with having empty default values, as I'm trying my best to achieve complete database normalization (at least 3NF) which is best practice for relational databases. Thanks a lot for your effort in this reply, got it working perfectly now, thanks to you ❤️

Comment: If you have `NOT NULL` columns, you must have every value filled every time you save a record in your PHP code. Defining a default for the column is just a safety blanket.

Comment: And children should be plural of child; Laravel uses Doctrine's naming code which does have an entry for that: https://github.com/doctrine/inflector/blob/1.3.x/lib/Doctrine/Common/Inflector/Inflector.php#L59